# How to initiate a SIP (session initiation protocol) and transfer media (voice) through RTP (real time transport protocol)

Tags: python, sip, rtp

I am working on a project where I need to write a server to initiate SIP sessions with connecting clients and a remote soft-switch. Once the session has been initiated, voice streams should be transmitted back and forth between the end-points using real time transport protocol. Given my above scenario, I have a few questions on how to go about solving this problem.

1)  **How is SIP initiated?**
I do understand SIP are usually initiated by SIP clients in IP telecommunication devices. But if you want to initiate SIP sessions programatically, how do you do it without a SIP client? Currently I am using Python, so I came across a few libraries. Like [simplesip](https://github.com/AGProjects/python-sipsimple/blob/master/README) (which looks overly complicated and not sure if it can do what I want), then there is [sippy](https://github.com/sippy/b2bua), which looks promising.

I was also thinking if you can manually create SIP/SDP packets manually through the program and try to initiate a SIP session. I feel like I am reinventing the wheel here by trying to do that. So my question is how do initiate a SIP session programatically? If libraries are used, what are some good libraries. Or is it OK to create and send SIP packets manually in a program?

2) **When RTP is created during SIP, how can this RTP channel be referenced to a remote device so that it can use this referenced RTP channel?**
When researching online, I was told that SIP doesn't provide services to transmit media but just creates a session. Actually RTP does the heavy lifting of doing things in real time. So when a RTP is initiated what does this really mean in a software terminology. Is it a object which can which can be referenced to a device? How can I even add streams of media to this RTP?

Comment: Is the soft-switch also a SIP user agent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Setting up and maintaining SIP sessions is done by sending and receiving messages in the Internet Message Format (see [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322)): text messages, usually sent using UDP or TCP. It's all about what message to send and when. SIP libraries can help you with that (and with sending/receiving RTP streams) but you can easily do it yourself if you just know how to send UDP messages.

In short: to set up a SIP session you send a SIP INVITE request message, the other party returns SIP INVITE response message and you complete the session initiation by sending a SIP ACK message. Normally the INVITE request will contain an SDP offer in its body, specifying what kind of media the client is willing/able to receive and on which IP address/port. The INVITE response then contains an SDP answer specifying the same for the other party.

The SIP protocol is described in [RFC 3261](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261), SDP in [SDP 4566](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4566). If you google a bit you can find plenty of examples for SIP communication.

2. You're right in that SIP doesn't provide services to transmit/receive media streams. SIP can be used to let another party know you want to set up a media session and negotiate the specifics. Sending/receiving the media stream has to be done seperately; again you could use a library or do it yourself.

An RTP stream (see [RFC 3550](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550)) is just an example of such a media stream. Sending an RTP stream means sending a continuous stream of RTP packets (usually as part of UDP packets). Every packet contains RTP data: an RTP header and the RTP payload (the actual audio samples).

Mode of operation:
The sending party samples its local audio. Every time it has (e.g.) 20 ms worth of audio samples it creates an RTP packet and sends this as payload in an UDP packet. This means it sends a packet every 20 ms, creating a stream of packets: the RTP stream. The receiving party buffers these packets and uses the audio samples in each packet to recreate the audio.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey mate thank you for your answer. I actually managed to generate SIP messages by writing my own SIP library. I tested my script with a SIP server running on the same network everything works fine. But when I try to send my invites across an firewall to a SIP server sitting across another network, my packets are blocked by the firewall. I have posted a new question regarding this issue. Please provide some insights on this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48473828/whats-the-encoding-used-in-sip-or-in-sip-alg-in-firewalls

Comment: I have. SIP and firewalls (NAT) prove to be a difficult match. Mainly because IP addresses used in the SIP messages are valid on only one side of the firewall.

Comment: @Vino is your code is open source... i am working on somethign similar/...can you please share few resource.