# What's the encoding used in SIP or in SIP ALG in Firewalls

Tags: python, encoding, sip, firewall, sip-server

I have written a Python 3 script to emulate SIP call transfer event. The script was working successfully when tested with a SIP server sitting on the same network. When I tested with a SIP server sitting across a firewall, all data sent by the script to port 5060 of the SIP server is blocked by the Firewall. Data sent on any other port than 5060 are allowed across the Firewall. This made me presume that the packets are blocked by SIP ALG protocol running on port 5060 of the Firewall (Fortigate). To gather more information about the scenario, I tested with a command line tool called SIPp. SIPp was used to send SIP invites across the Firewall to the SIP server to port 5060. The invites generated by this tool was successfully sent across the Firewall. Then I made sure the format of the messages generated by SIPp and my script are identical. Even then the messages generated by my script are not going through the Firewall. My situation is quite complicated because there is no log for the Firewall available. I was doing some research online came across this protocol called SIP ALG implemented on most routers and Firewalls. I do understand SIP ALG used correct private/public IPs of the SIP user agent. But in my situation I don't have plausible reason other than SIP ALG blocking my messages to port 5060. If SIP ALG is the culprit and it only blocks the messages generated by my script not SIPp, is then because of different encoding used in the message composition? If yes, what's the standard encoding used for SIP? I am currently using utf-8 on Python 3. Any insights is appreciated.

Comment: It might have to do with the payload in your SIP message if the firewall uses deep packet inspection. I have come across a situation where Fortigate blocked SIP messages because the RTP ports in the SDP offer would be blocked according to the firewall rules.

Comment: You could try sending an OPTIONS message first, instead of an INVITE. This reduces the chance the message is blocked due to deep packet inspection. And compare your INVITE message with the one from SIPp; this might give some insight too.

Comment: Hey Buq. Thanks for your answer. I did the packet inspection with SIPp and my script. Then I modified my script to generate a SIP invite exactly like the one generated by SIPp but for my surprise invite my from my script is blocked again. I have no idea whats going on. I am going to try and send an OPTIONS message and report back here.